# Using two parameters in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement where I need to provide two report parameters for a report builder.The first parameter will present two types, National ID or Mobile ID in a drop down list.If we select NID and enter value for NID into second parameter it should show the common customer details of that NID.If we select Mobile Id type and enter mobile number for the second parameter it should show the common details of that mobile number.

Please it's really appriciate if anybody can help

Comment: Is your dataset based on Sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your dataset's Sql query to use your parameters as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ((@Param1 = 'National ID') AND (NationalID = @Param2)) 
   OR ((@Param1 = 'Mobile ID') AND (MobileID = @Param2))
```